# how to get menu is hiding code in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I am using the theme(wordpress) that came with user role . if i login with admin role all menu in wp-admin appear which is correct . but when i login from admin with role subscriber all admin menu are hiding . 
I have search functions.php but there is no code to hide menu . after spending lot of time in searching code of hiding there is no result .

can some one tell which are  the possible file where hiding code could be  present ?. it is taking a lot of time to search a code .

```
function my_function_admin_bar(){
    echo "Access";exit;
    return true;
}
add_filter( 'show_admin_bar' , 'my_function_admin_bar');
```

**updted functions.php**

```
 <?php
    @ob_start();



    define('velocity_FUNCTIONS', get_template_directory() . '/functions/');
    define('velocity_THEME', get_template_directory_uri());
    define('velocity_JAVASCRIPT', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js');
    define('velocity_CSS', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css');
    define('velocity_TYPE', get_template_directory_uri() . '/type');
    $result = add_role( 'CustomP', __(

    'Customp' ),

    array(

    'read' => true, // true allows this capability
    'edit_posts' => true, // Allows user to edit their own posts
    'edit_pages' => true, // Allows user to edit pages
    'edit_others_posts' => true, // Allows user to edit others posts not just their own
    'create_posts' => true, // Allows user to create new posts
    'manage_categories' => true, // Allows user to manage post categories
    'publish_posts' => true, // Allows the user to publish, otherwise posts stays in draft mode
    'edit_themes' => false, // false denies this capability. User can’t edit your theme
    'install_plugins' => false, // User cant add new plugins
    'update_plugin' => false, // User can’t update any plugins
    'update_core' => false // user cant perform core updates

    )

    );



    /* Admin Functionality */
    if (is_admin()){

   function my_function_admin_bar(){
        echo "Access";exit;
        return true;
    }
    add_filter( 'show_admin_bar' , 'my_function_admin_bar');
        require_once(velocity_FUNCTIONS . '/page_options/theme_page_options.php');
        require_once(velocity_FUNCTIONS . '/theme_options/theme_settings.php');
        if(function_exists("wpb_map")){
            require_once(velocity_FUNCTIONS . '/theme_builder.php');
        }
        require_once(velocity_FUNCTIONS . '/thundercodes/thundericons.php');
        if(get_option('velocity_first_import')!="on"){
            require_once(velocity_FUNCTIONS . '/theme_activate.php');
        }
        require_once(velocity_FUNCTIONS . '/theme_plugins.php');
        require_once(velocity_FUNCTIONS . '/theme_startmessage.php');
        require_once(velocity_FUNCTIONS . '/theme_featured_image_preview.php');
        require_once(velocity_FUNCTIONS . '/theme_docu.php');
    }

    require_once(velocity_FUNCTIONS . '/navigation/sweet-custom-menu.php');

    /* Theme Functionality */
    require_once(velocity_FUNCTIONS . '/theme_support.php');
    require_once(velocity_FUNCTIONS . '/aq_resize.php');
    require_once(velocity_FUNCTIONS . '/theme_functions.php');
    require_once(velocity_FUNCTIONS . '/theme_pagination.php');
    require_once(velocity_FUNCTIONS . '/theme_javascriptcss.php');
    require_once(velocity_FUNCTIONS . '/theme_widgets.php');
    require_once(velocity_FUNCTIONS . '/theme_sidebars.php');
    require_once(velocity_FUNCTIONS . '/theme_post_comments.php');
    require_once(velocity_FUNCTIONS . '/theme_breadcrumbs.php');

    if(!is_admin()){

    require_once(velocity_FUNCTIONS . '/theme_options/theme_style_generate.php');
    }

    /* Theme Language */
    require_once(velocity_FUNCTIONS . '/theme_language.php');

    /* Media Box */
    function load_media_box(){
     if(function_exists(wp_enqueue_media())) wp_enqueue_media();
    }
    add_action('admin_enqueue_scripts', 'load_media_box'); 
    ?>
    <?php


    function my_login_redirect($redirect_to, $request) {
    $redirect_url = get_bloginfo( 'url' ) . '/wp-admin/';

    return $redirect_url;
    }
    add_filter("login_redirect", "my_login_redirect", 10, 3);



    /* new code */
        /*
        global $wp_roles;
        foreach ( $wp_roles->role_names as $role => $name ) :
        if ( current_user_can( $role ) )
                echo 'This user has a role of ' . $role;
         endforeach;*/

    ?>
```

Comment: Is the code for the menu "gone" / not in the page at all, or is it simply hidden with css? Open your browser's console / inspect the code with it and find out.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [why menubar is hiding in wordpress admin](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32951357/why-menubar-is-hiding-in-wordpress-admin)

Comment: Yeh i also inspected code but not getting any clue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's an option to hide the Admin menu from specific User / User Group. You can enable / disable the feature by Editing the User, and check / uncheck:

> Show Toolbar when viewing site

---

**UPDATE** Alternatively, you can make use of the `show_admin_bar(true)` to show the admin bar in `functions.php` in your theme.

```
if(is_admin()) {
  show_admin_bar(true);
}
```

Reference: https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/show_admin_bar

Comment: i don't want to change user role . where can be the php code to hide menu

Comment: You don't have to. This is per user permission.

Comment: can i change permission using php code , instead of manually changing

Comment: Use this function : https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/show_admin_bar

Comment: should i place  show_admin_bar( false ); function in functions.php or some where else

Comment: Yes , in `functions.php`, add a filter just as the WordPress Codex page suggests , along with other `add_filter()` functions.

Comment: i have written the above function  my_function_admin_bar in functions.php but surprisingly the control is not going to function my_function_admin_bar .

Comment: You'd better post more codes. And are you editing the theme in use?

Comment: @ Raptor there are many files in wp which file code should i post ?

Comment: What if under the `if (is_admin()){` line, add `show_admin_bar(true);` ?

Comment: should i write the above function under if (is_admin()){ is_admin

Comment: Admin bar is for admin only, isn't it ? You can decide the logic anyway.

Comment: i have written a code of  my_function_admin_bar in is admin then also the control is not going inside function

Comment: i am not getting 'Try the function first'

Comment: Use this function: `show_admin_bar(true);` in `if (is_admin()){` block

Comment: made changes but no result . i think functions.php is not making any difference .